# ViewBag property not getting set when get action is called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag, selectlistitem

In MVC project,EF DB first, I am using a ViewBag property to show a list of values in a dropdown. Here is my get method and post method for the same.-

```
[ HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            using (var context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
            {
    ViewBag.Colors = new SelectList(context.Products.Select(a => 
    a.Color).Distinct().ToList());
            }

            return View();

 [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("Create")]
        public ActionResult CreatePost()
        {
            var producttocreate = new Product();
        try
            {
                UpdateModel(producttocreate);
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    using (var context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
                    {
                        context.Products.Add(producttocreate);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(producttocreate);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return View(producttocreate);
            }

    }
```

Here the property ViewBag.Colors is the proprty in question. When I am getting an exception on Post I want to pass the model and return the same Create view again. However , even though I have code to set ViewBag.Colors everytime the Create Get method is called , it is not being set and I am getting an error when Create View is rendering  -

**The ViewData item that has the key 'Color' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'**.

I did find out in some other post that the reason for this exception is that ViewBag.Colors is null , but I do not understand why. Why is it not getting set when View is called from Post Action Method? And what is the solution to this?

Comment: So, your code works on initial page load, but is giving an exception when you try and submit the form and are returned with the same view?  Is the drop-down a required field on the form?

Comment: M12 Bennett - yes it works on initial page load . When I am posting the data , if the post is successful, I want to be returned to an Index view  if it is not successful, I want it to return the same view. It is at this point that I expect ViewBag.Colors to be set again in the GET Method as it is there in the code , but it is set to null.

Comment: M12 Bennett - about the other part of the question , no its not a required field , as in , required attribute is not applied on the property in the Model Class.

Comment: Okay, understood.  To be clear, if the post is unsuccessful, it does not go back to the `HttpGet` method.  It will stay in the HttpPost method, which means that you will have to set the `ViewBag.Colors` again in the HttpPost method.  I've had this happen to me in the past, and I usually set it right at the beginning of the method.  That's up to you though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before

```
return View(producttocreate);
```

do like this

```
ViewData["Colors"] = new SelectList(_context.Products, "Id", "Color", ColorId);
```

Comment: Faith Alac - you mean , set the viewdata or ViewBag again in the Post Action Method as well? I dont understand why I would require that. In the Get Action Method I am setting it , so when I call that method from inside the Post Action Method , why is it still null?

Comment: first u select in  public IActionResult Create()  then  [HttpPost] u need to know selected value.

Comment: I guess then the only way to go is to populate ViewBag again in Post method. Although quiqs answer of doing RedirectToAction() was also correct.But since I am using this suggestion, I am marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `ViewBag.Colors` is null is because when there is an error in the POST, you are not redirecting to the (GET) Create action. Instead, you are sending the model back to the view, bypassing the (GET) Create action, thus not populating the ViewBag. If you did `RedirectToAction("Create");` instead of `View(producttocreate)`, ViewBag.Colors would be populated again.

Comment: quiqs - I will try RedirectToAction("Create"} if thats the case. But then which method gets called when I write View(model)?

Comment: I tried RedirectToAction("Create") , its not what I want.It is clearing all the fields, plus, I had a CustomValidation, that message didnt come. I want the fields I entered to be intact.

Comment: View() is the method. What this method does is, if no argument is passed, it looks for a View of the same name as the enclosing action to display your object. If the name of a View is supplied, it looks for a view with that name. If you want to keep the ModelState, then @FaithAlac has got your answer. Populate the ViewBag in your POST after ModelState.IsValid fails and before returning the view.

Comment: 'it looks for a View of the same name as the enclosing action to display your object' - yes , i do want that , because I want to stay in Create View. About populating the ViewBag before POST , my hesitancy with that is I am already populating it in the GET method, so it would look odd to do it everywhere. But if that is the only solution , then I would ask how else to go about it when POST fails. Every tutorial I see uses this way , why dont they face this problem?In other words - Is creating a ViewModel the only option to hold such values?

Comment: A ViewBag's lifetime goes from either controller to view, view to controller, or controller to controller. It's a one way trip. After that, it ceases to exist. That's why you need to populate it again in the POST, but only if you need the same view, need to keep the values in the ModelState, and display the errors to the user, all of which you want.